# Source code is unable to detect include file with angle bracket notation

Tags: c++, cmake

The following CMake project has two issues:

1. It requires `dummy.cc` files to let the `CMake` know that we are using C++ language. Otherwise, we get `CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target:` error.
2. `#include` directives are using angle bracket symbol which the compiler cannot recongnize.

**Output:**

```
====================[ Clean | Debug ]===========================================
"C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\JetBrains\CLion 2022.1.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build "C:\Users\pc\Documents\__protein design\hydrogen bond\data_struct_and_alg\cmake-build-debug" --target clean -j 3
[1/1] Cleaning all built files...
Cleaning... 0 files.

Clean finished

====================[ Build | all | Debug ]=====================================
"C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\JetBrains\CLion 2022.1.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build "C:\Users\pc\Documents\__protein design\hydrogen bond\data_struct_and_alg\cmake-build-debug" --target all -j 3
[1/5] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main_exe.dir/main.cc.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/main_exe.dir/main.cc.obj 
"C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\JetBrains\CLion 2022.1.3\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe"   -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main_exe.dir/main.cc.obj -MF CMakeFiles\main_exe.dir\main.cc.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/main_exe.dir/main.cc.obj -c "C:/Users/pc/Documents/__protein design/hydrogen bond/data_struct_and_alg/main.cc"
C:/Users/pc/Documents/__protein design/hydrogen bond/data_struct_and_alg/main.cc:1:10: fatal error: core\core.hh: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <core\core.hh>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
[2/5] Building CXX object core/data_struct/CMakeFiles/algorithm.dir/dummy.cc.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

How can I resolve these two issues?

[image]

**algorithm.hh**

```
#ifndef ALG_HH
#define ALG_HH

#include <iostream>

#include <core\data_struct\data_struct.hh>

void print_algorithm()
{
    std::cout<<"algorithm";
}

void data_strcut_and_alg_2()
{
    print_data_struct();
    print_algorithm();
}
#endif
```

**data_struct.hh**

```
#ifndef DATA_STRUCT_HH
#define DATA_STRUCT_HH

#include <iostream>

#include <core\algorithm\algorithm.hh>

void print_data_struct()
{
    std::cout<<"data structure";
}

void data_strcut_and_alg_1()
{
    print_data_struct();
    print_algorithm();
}

#endif
```

**core.hh**

```
#ifndef CORE_HH
#define CORE_HH
#include <iostream>
#include <core\data_struct\data_struct.hh>
#include <core\algorithm\algorithm.hh>

void print_core()
{
    print_data_struct();
    print_algorithm();
}
#endif
```

**main.cc**

```
#include <core\core.hh>
#include <core\algorithm\algorithm.hh>
#include <core\data_struct\data_struct.hh>

int main()
{
    print_algorithm();
    print_data_struct();
    data_strcut_and_alg_1();
    data_strcut_and_alg_2();
    print_core();
}
```

**core\CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_subdirectory(algorithm
        data_struct)

add_library(core
        core.hh)

target_link_libraries(core
        algorithm
        data_struct)
```

**core\algorithm\CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library(algorithm
        algorithm.hh
        dummy.cc
        )
```

**core\data_struct\CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library(data_struct
        data_struct.hh
        dummy.cc
        )
```

**root\CMakeLists.txt**

```
#root

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(BioShellHydrogenBondWithDriverProgram CXX)

add_subdirectory(core)

add_executable(main_exe main.cc)

target_link_libraries(main_exe
        core
        )
```

Comment: Don't use backslashes in #include, it's non standard, use right slashes.

Comment: Your algorithm and data_struct cmake files are missing ../.. in include paths.

Comment: Sidenote: Since you've defined your free functions in the header files, you should make them `inline` or else you will run into _one definition rule_ violations sooner or later.

Comment: Also, use of `<>` in `#include` is conventionally reserved for system-defined headers (since the standard specifies that such headers are found in an implementation-defined manner).   For third party headers (that are not normally system-defined headers) use of `""` form of `#include` is encouraged.     Either way, still preferable to use forward-slashes, not backslashes.

Comment: @Peter, I am not writing my own c++ source code. I am trying to compile and link a c++ source code that is a stripped down version of a much larger off-the-shelf code base. I am stuck with the problem that I posted.

Comment: `core\algorithm\algorithm.hh` looks for algorithm.hh in core/..., but no one's told the compiler where core/... is. When using angle bracketed includes you typically need to tell the compiler where to start looking. That's usually a `-I<path>` on the compiler command line.  There are no `-I`s in `"C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\JetBrains\CLion 2022.1.3\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe"   -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main_exe.dir/main.cc.obj -MF CMakeFiles\main_exe.dir\main.cc.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/main_exe.dir/main.cc.obj -c "C:/Users/pc/Documents/__protein design/hydrogen bond/data_struct_and_alg/main.cc"`

Comment: I'm no cmake guru, but I usually specify the search locations with `target_include_directories`

Comment: @user366312  Whether its your code or "off-the-shelf code base", there are various reasons to use `""` form of `#include` rather than `<>`.    The fact it is done in source code (the headers are part of the source) compounds the problems due to misuse of slashes and makes it almost impossible for a build script to sensibly fix the problem - it is necessary to edit the headers to replace `\ ` with `/` and, while you're doing that, it would be advisable to use `""` rather than `<>`, which relies even more on implementation-defined (i.e. compiler/preprocessor specific) behaviours.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix: in `root/CMakeLists.txt`, add `include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})`. But this doesn't really express the desired dependencies, in that files in `algorithm` and `data_struct` could then include any header files in the same directory as `main.cc`.

Better, create another layer to express that there are libraries, and tests (or executables) that use those libraries. Along these lines: create a `lib` and `test` directory under the root directory. And under `test`, create a `main` directory. Move the .h and .cc and CMakeLists.txt files accordingly.

```
data_struct_and_alg
- lib
  - core
    - algorithm
      algorithm.hh
    - data_struct
      data_struct.hh
    core.hh
- test
  - main
    main.cc
```

This structure allows more libraries under `lib`, and more tests or executables, under `test`.

In the `core` directory the CMakelists can have

```
add_subdirectory(algorithm)
add_subdirectory(data_struct)
```

In the top-level CMakelists.txt,

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
add_subdirectory(lib)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

The CMakeLists.txt in test can simply `add_subdirectory(main)`.

(As others have said, backslashes in include paths are best replaced with forward slashes, as backslashes won't work on clang (on Windows and Linux) or gcc (on linux), i.e. they're only good on Visual C++. And I'm assuming that the code is for illustrative purposes and there are .cc files in each library for implementing functions.)